# Content Search App

Tags: 2013, office-365, content-search-web-part

I'm running an Office 365 SharePoint 2013 install while we are setting up our own on-premise installation.

I'm trying to use the Content Search App and results are showing fine while designing and previewing my query but the same results are not shown once he query is saved and viewed from the site itself. I always get nothing on screen not even a title.

Is there something I'm missing here. I've trying to show the last three sites that meet a certain criteria but can't get anything to show on the page once I've created my query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this only occurs when view through an extended version of the web application. with a slightly different url.